# Extract Previous row Value based on Condition

Tags: r, dataset, data-science

To analyse some data for a paper I need to extract the entire row previous to a met condition.

For example I have an error column and a Response Time column

```
Error    ResponseTime
0        0.22
0        0.28
1        0.89
0        0.92
1        0.21
```

Desired output

```
Error    ResponseTime
0        0.28
0        0.92
```

So if error == 1
extract previous row and put it in a new dataframe.

I tried to use the zoo library but I could not manage to make it work.

I tried this solution :

```
Dfa1test <- Dfa1test[c(FALSE, head(Dfa1test$error, -1) == 1), , drop = FALSE]
```

The problem with the last solution is that I get row + 1  and not row -1.

I tried to find other solutions but I did not get close to my desired output.

Comment: Just do `df[which(df$Error == 1) - 1, ]`

Comment: @Rich Scriven When doing this I get row +1 instead of row -1

Comment: I got the right answer.

Comment: Never mind it worked, it seems my test dataframe was buggy. Thank you !

Comment: @PierreJardinet  Suppose if the adjacent elements in Error are 1 (more general case), then what will be the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df1[,.I[which(Error==1)-1]]]
#   Error ResponseTime
#1:     0         0.28
#2:     0         0.92
```

If we need only the rows which have 0 as previous element in 'Error' when the current element is 1

```
setDT(df)[df[, .I[which(shift(Error, fill=999)==0 & Error==1)-1]]]
```

NOTE: In this example, both of them give the same result

Comment: Hi akrun, Thank you for your answer! Although I used Rich Scriven answer. Will try yours out !